# Do valueTransformer in kafka stream can have access to tombstone?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

is it possible to have access to the tombstone that an upstream Ktable process ?

Let say I would like to apply a logic to every deletion that happen to an upstream KTable, that is, do ValueTransformer get forwarded delete Event ?

`kTable.transform(delete Event)`

if not, is there another way to achieve this ?

Comment: I think the answer can be in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65596410/delete-data-from-ktable-that-has-a-custom-stream-streampartitioner

Comment: Thanks for this. BTW did plenty of test and no transformer set after a Ktable can not see the delete event. I have a specific use case and will definitely post it.

Comment: My use case is with KTable not KStream.